# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar una barra de carga hasta que todos los elementos de la página estén cargados, incluidos vídeos subidos al hosting?

Tags: javascript

a ver si alguien me puede echar un cable con Javascript.

Tengo una página donde utilizo vídeos como recursos gráficos. No quiero cargarlos a un servidor externos porque me dan muchos problemas y necesito versiones premium para ultilzar solo la imagen y audio sin logotipos ni nada referente al servidor externo (como Vimeo, donde necesito una cuenta premium).

Me gustaría que apareciera una barra de carga que muestre el proceso de carga de la página, en especial los vídeos (cargados desde mi hosting). O sea que al terminar de cargar la barra, la página sea visible y los vídeos se reproduzcan justo al cargar.

¿Cómo podría hacer esto en Javascript?

Le agradecería un monton al que me pueda ayudar.

Answer (score 1):

Mas allá de que sea o no una idea buena (y factible), yo probaría a crear una barra con HTML, y situarla al inicio del *body*. Darle la apariencia y posición con un CSS reducido incluido en el *head* y mediante un pequeño script JavaScript, tambien en el *head* ocultar la barra cuando la página este cargada, p.e.

```
<script>
    window.onload = () => {
        document.querySelector('#load_bar').style.display = 'none';
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Hola! Sí, no es muy buena idea . pero es un portafolio personal y solo será para que lo vean agencias de diseño. Una cosa: este método tambien sirve para los vídeos? O sea, cuando se quite la barra los videos se reproducirán sin lag? Gracias por tu respuesta!

Comment: Este script es solo para ocultar la barra.
Los vídeos se reproduciran cuando se carguen si así se lo indicas según el método que utilices, p.e. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_autoplay.asp